# Get quota output from cyradm (cyrus) in a bash script

Tags: bash, cyrus

I have am writing a script to list the quota of all the users in my LDAP directory. For this,
I use `ldapsearch` with the appropriate filters to get a list of my usernames in a file. Next I run that file through a while loop which reads the file line-by-line and uses a `here` document to send the username to the cyrus shell. This is what the loop looks like:

```
while read userName;do

        cyradm -u cyrus -w my_cyrus_password  localhost << sample
lq user/$userName 
sample

done</home/myuser/tempfiles/tempnames.txt
```

where `lq` is the cyradm command to list quota for a user.

I need to output the username and its corresponding quota into a file. How do I do that from within the loop?

Comment: Is there any type in the 'input the username and its corresponding quota into a file'? Should it be 'output the username and its corresponding quota to a file' instead?

Comment: @JtheRocker - Sorry, was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Try this -> `echo $(cyradm -u cyrus -w my_cyrus_password  localhost << sample
lq user/$userName 
sample) > outfile`

Comment: I get the following error `./testscript: line 12: warning: here-document at line 12 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'sample')`

Comment: @JtheRocker - Fized it. Moved the `) > outfile` section to a new line. That fixed it. Could you update it as the answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you tried this ->

```
while read userName;do

echo $(cyradm -u cyrus -w my_cyrus_password localhost << sample
lq user/$userName 
sample
) >> outfile

done</home/myuser/tempfiles/tempnames.txt
```

Comment: I also found `>> outfile` appends to the file (since we are in a `while` loop)

Comment: Yes. Correct >> appends